# Magento: How to LEFT-JOIN 'catalog/category' fields to 'sales/order_item' collection?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, left-join

I'm trying to left-join some of the `catalog/category` attributes to a `sales/order_item` collection.

*For example:* a satisfying  result will let me add the category-name to the order-item data.

- I know I can use the categories flat table, but I need to know if it's possible to join the EAV-collection and how.
- It must be done with one mysql query (Not by looping through the order items or something like that...)
- I know that it might lead to duplicated rows if the product has more than 1 category, that's  exactly what I need.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you would do it in the Magento world. Note the "group by" in the collection. This is because with a left join, when you have more than one result for the same primary key, Varien_Data_Collection throws an error that an item with that ID already exists. Anyways, I wrote this up for you and tested it.

My answer also gets the store value for Category Name and falls back on the default value if a store value does not exist.

```
<?php

include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$itemModel            = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item');
$itemResource         = $itemModel->getResource();
$categoryProductTable = $itemResource->getTable('catalog/category_product');

$categoryModel    = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$categoryResource = $categoryModel->getResource();
$name             = $categoryResource->getAttribute('name');
$nameTable        = $name->getBackendTable();
$defaultStoreId = Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID;

$collection = $itemModel->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('category_product_table' => $categoryProductTable), 'main_table.product_id = category_product_table.product_id', array());
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('store_category_name_table' => $nameTable),
                                   "store_category_name_table.entity_id = category_product_table.category_id AND
                                    store_category_name_table.attribute_id = {$name->getAttributeId()} AND
                                    store_category_name_table.entity_type_id = {$name->getEntityTypeId()} AND
                                    store_category_name_table.store_id = main_table.store_id",
                                   array()
);
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('default_category_name_table' => $nameTable),
                                   "default_category_name_table.entity_id = category_product_table.category_id AND
                                    default_category_name_table.attribute_id = {$name->getAttributeId()} AND
                                    default_category_name_table.entity_type_id = {$name->getEntityTypeId()} AND
                                    default_category_name_table.store_id = {$defaultStoreId}",
                                   array()
);
$collection->getSelect()->columns(array('category_name' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COALESCE(store_category_name_table.value,default_category_name_table.value)')));
$collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.item_id');

echo $collection->getFirstItem()->getCategoryName();
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try.

Comment: Cool. Just FYI, the last line `echo $collection->getFirstItem()->getCategoryName();` is just an example on how to echo out the first item in the collection so that you can see the Category name in it's data.

Comment: Tested & works as expected. 
Thanks again @ShawnAbramson, you saved me a lot of time.

Notes / Additions:
I actually needed that to be grouped by other columns, so I removed "$collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.item_id');". 
This led to the known collection error of "Item with the same id already exist...", which I solved by reseting the select columns and adding the required ones while replacing 'item_id' with an alias:
$collection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
$collection->getSelect()->columns(array('order_item_id' => 'item_id'));

Answer (score 1):

You could do sth. like this:

```php
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

$sql = 'SELECT `main_table`.*, `products`.*, `cname`.* FROM `sales_flat_order_item` AS `main_table`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `products` ON main_table.product_id=products.product_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS `cname` ON `products`.`category_id`=`cname`.`entity_id`
';

$result = $readConnection->fetchAll($sql);
```

Comment: codedge, please see my answer. it is much more reliable to run through the magento methods to obtain this data.

Comment: @ShawnAbramson I totally agree with you - the better approach is using Magentos ORM.